# How to listen to GET requests using only http with node? No express

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm wondering how to listen to http get requests with only "require http" instead o f express.

This is what I have now:

```
let http = require('http');
let server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello, World!\n');
});
server.listen(8443);
console.log('Server running on port 8443');
```

I want to listen to get requests, and console.log the url. and if there is any other request i want to print ("bad request").

Comment: Then you need to check what method was used [http: message.method](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_method) and if it is not `GET` then send another response.

Comment: FYI. You'd send a `400 Bad Request` to a valid url with invalid parameters. What you should do is send a 404 instead.

Comment: Can you give me a small example of how to use http: message.method?

Comment: @manonthemat If a resource exists and only supports `GET`,  and you send request with another method e.g, `POST`, then the server should return `405 Method Not Allowed`.

Comment: @t.niese true, good point.

Answer (score 10):

You need to check what method was used using [http: message.method](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_method) and if it is not `GET` then send another response.

```
'use strict'
let http = require('http');
let server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if( req.method === 'GET' ) {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Hello, World!\n');
  } else {
    res.writeHead(405, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    res.end('Method Not Allowed\n');
  }
});
server.listen(8443);
console.log('Server running on port 8443');
```